# Collapsing includes blank lines in Notepad++ when scripting in Vbscript

Tags: vbscript, notepad++

When I wirte the following example code (in VBscript) in **Notepad++**

```
dim X

X = Array(  "string1", _
            "string2", _
            "string3" )



Wscript.Echo X(1)
```

it looks as follows:

[image]

As you can see, the three blank lines are inside the code block which one can collapse and uncollapse, which is an annoying behavior. I'd rather have these three lines outside the array group like here, but without `REM`:

[image]

Is there a setting of Notepad++ I am missing to get the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

You can utilized custom language defined settings to make custom fold begin and end objects. This will allow you to insert start and end paramaters within your code so folding done by your configuration.

Here, the language is set to VB and includes the blank spaced lines.

[image: Long folded array]

Click on the User Defined Languages Icon(sorry for bad drawing....).

[image]

Here, i've saved the user language as **Custvbs** and applied `'{` and `'}` as my start/end blocks for folding. There is an additional field for secondary folding labelled `Folding in code 2 style (seperators needed)`

[image: user define language form]

And here is the resulting custom fold:

[image: Custom Fold]

Comment: But this way all presets of `VB` are lost, for example highlighting. I will try to find a xml-file for vbscript to modify in the web.

Comment: You can fast toggle between VB and your custom config under the language menu as well. It will unfold all of your code though.

Answer (score 0):

How about removing the surplus blank lines. You can do this by selecting `TextFX -> TextFX Edit -> Delete Surplus Blank Lines`